# Defective Iterative DFS implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, depth-first-search

I have been practicing algorithms and data structures. And I am trying to write an iterative version of DFS.

Here is my code:

```
def dfsvisit_iterative(self,startVertex):
    stack = []
    stack.append(startVertex)
    startVertex.setColor('gray')
    self.time += 1
    startVertex.setDiscovery(self.time)

    while stack:
        tos = stack[-1]

        for nextVertex in tos.getConnections():
            if nextVertex.getColor() == 'white':
                nextVertex.setColor('gray')
                nextVertex.setPred(tos)
                self.time += 1
                nextVertex.setDiscovery(self.time)
                stack.append(nextVertex)
                tos = stack[-1]

        tos.setColor('black')
        self.time += 1
        tos.setFinish(self.time)
        stack.pop()
```

However it is not working because I cannot update the loop `nextVertex in tos.getConnections():` on the fly as I change `tos` at the bottom of the loop.

How would you fix that? I know I can do it with recursion but I'd like an iterative solution close to my version.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't mean to change `tos` inside your for loop. In DFS you push all adjacent nodes in some arbitrary order onto a stack and when pushing is finished, you take the most recent one, i.e the top of stack and keep doing that.

So you don't need this line `tos = stack[-1]` inside your for loop at all! Also you're popping the **recently** added node after it's been added in your for loop, which is not what you want. So you need to move `stack.pop()` line before your for loop. This also makes sense because in DFS you pop (remove) one from stack, push it's adjacent ones, and repeat. So you do this:

```
    while stack:
        tos = stack[-1]
        stack.pop()

        for nextVertex in tos.getConnections():
            if nextVertex.getColor() == 'white':
                nextVertex.setColor('gray')
                nextVertex.setPred(tos)
                self.time += 1
                nextVertex.setDiscovery(self.time)
                stack.append(nextVertex)

        tos.setColor('black')
        self.time += 1
        tos.setFinish(self.time)
```

### What you instead wanted in your question:

If, for whatever reason (maybe experimenting?), you need to do something that you've described in your question, you may try using a temporary tos for iteration. Like this:

```
while stack:
        tos = stack[-1]
        temp_tos = tos

        for nextVertex in temp_tos.getConnections():
            if nextVertex.getColor() == 'white':
                nextVertex.setColor('gray')
                nextVertex.setPred(tos)
                self.time += 1
                nextVertex.setDiscovery(self.time)
                stack.append(nextVertex)
                tos = stack[-1]
```

Note that I added only a single line before your for loop and changed the for loop's head a little.  And the rest is up to you.